# Groovy abstract classes constructors and inheritance

Tags: groovy, constructor, abstract-class, subclass

I have an abstract java class which has a constructor and I'm extending it from a groovy class. (the idea is to keep the java class as a contract inside the app and load external groovy classes that implement certain constructors and methods)

How can I force in Groovy to implement an abstract super class's constructor?
Does Groovy allow to force the implementation of the abstract parent class's constructor?

The thing is that the Eclipse Groovy IDE is not forcing me to implement the constructor of the parent class in the subclass, I thougth Groovy would create it automatically and so that was the reason to not forcing it. However at run time when trying to get the constructor using java reflection fails it fails if I don't define the parent constructor in the subclass.

(I have 0 experience in Groovy)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like an unchecked situation in the compiler. Upon decompiling, the extending class gets an empty constructor. Tests should get you covered, since this situation doesn't work in runtime.

I don't know of a way to use this class; i tried the ways i know:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  String string
  Integer integer
  AbstractClass(String string, Integer integer) {
    this.string = string
    this.integer = integer
  }
}

class ImplClass extends AbstractClass { }

// every constructor fails
abs1 = new ImplClass('a', 1)

abs2 = [string: 'b', integer: 2] as ImplClass

abs3 = new ImplClass(abs: 'c', a: 3)

abs4 = ImplClass [string:'d', integer:4]
```

Neither of them worked in runtime, but compiled fine ;-). The situation is more about compile error vs runtime error. Maybe filling a JIRA?

On the other way around, if you needed to inherit the constructors, you could go for `@groovy.transfom.InheritConstructors` in the extending class. This way you would have the constructors without needing to call `super()` explicitly.